# Apache Processes/Clients per Page View

Tags: apache-2.2, performance, configuration

With Apache, if `MaxClients` is set to `150`, does that mean Apache will try to serve up to 150 concurrent requests, and queue subsequent requests until all one of the 150 clients is available to serve? This assumes `KeepAlive` is off.

Also, if `ServerCount` is `2`, does this mean that Apache will create 2 instances that can each process 150 concurrent requests, or that 150 concurrent requests could be served across the 2 instances?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. `MaxClients` determines how many simultaneous requests will be serviced - futher requests will be queued.

`ServerCount` isn't a valid apache config option, I don't think - you may mean `StartServers`, which determines how many servers apache will start out running to serve the above number of client requests.

[This page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html) describes these directives in detail.

Comment: Also note that depending on whether you are using apache2-mpm-worker or apache2-mpm-prefork, these directives behave slightly differently.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's what `MaxClients` means.  Note that connections over your `ListenBacklog` will be dropped.

There is no `ServerCount` directive.  You probably don't mean `ServerLimit`; possibly then you're talking about `StartServers`, which is only about how many server instances get spawned initially.